# failed to open stream: Too many open files in vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php on line 113

Tags: magento2

I have a magento 2.3.x, after server restart, it shows the errors when i visit the homepage, any one know what is the problem?

> Warning: include(/home/m2/public_html/app/etc/config.php): failed to
> open stream: Too many open files in
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php
> on line 113
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
> '/home/m2/public_html/app/etc/config.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='/home/m2/public_html/generated/code:/home/m2/public_html/generated/code:/home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
> in
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php
> on line 113
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException:
> Invalid configuration file: '/home/m2/public_html/app/etc/config.php'
> in
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php:115
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(145):
> Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader->load() #1
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(70):
> Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig->load() #2
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(117):
> Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig->get() #3
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(211):
> Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #4
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(126):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory),
> '/home/m2/public...', Array) #5
> /home/m2/public_html/pub/index.php(37):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::creat in
> /home/m2/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php
> on line 115

Comment: please check php vesion.

Comment: did you find something to fix this?

Comment: @zuberbandi Please increase the "ulimit" value to "16384" on server side and it's working fine. 

For ulimit check using command - ulimit -aH OR ulimit -Sa